# in Chrome network tab "provisional headers are shown" , Authorization: Bearer JWT token

Tags: php, header, http-headers, authorization, token

I build api using php and i try to send request using react with `Authorization: Bearer` header.

The api is one server and the react app on localhost.
The problem is I get a

> provisional headers are shown

message in the Chrome network tab

[image]

[image]

The request

```
let fetchItems = async () => {
      try {
        let { data } = await axios.get("/api/items?target=myItems" , {
          headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("jwt")}`
          },
        });
        if (isMounted) {
          setItems(data)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully send requests to the PHP API with the Bearer Token Authorization header.